# Mutate state of children

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two components in my react application, one is parent and the second is the child.

I pass `fakedata` state as a props to child and then in child component save this as state of child component. But when I change something in child it's affect on parent state and I don't want this I want it's only effect on child state.

This is how I call child component from parent :

```
<FakeDataAddEditComponent  {...this.props} fakedata={{...this.state.fakedata}} />
```

and in child component this is how I set `fakedata` props to state :

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({fakedata:{...this.props.fakedata}},()=>{

     })
}
```

but when I change `fakedata` state in child it's also changend in `fakedata` of parent and I don't want this.

Comment: You probably mutate an object inside of fakedata. But why do you want to store the same information in both the parent and the child. It's better to only store the state in the parent and pass the relevant parts as props to child components. Also see the docs about [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, the reason you are seeing this behaviour is because Javascript passes a reference to the original object down the props and to the state of child component. When you update the child component it is the same instance as the parent is holding.

To fix the problem you should use `Object.assign` to make a copy of the object, however keep in ming that you will run into problems with nested objects.

Also, if parent object mutates the state in any way after the child state changed it will pass *old* object as props to the child. 
In general you're trying to do something you shouldn't do because you will run into trouble.

On a high level you should go for a proper state management solution like Redux of Flux.